# ngResource save() strange behaviour

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Can someone please shed some light on this?

```
var discountResource = $resource(GLOBALS.apiPath + 'discounts/:id');
var discountResponse = discountResource.save($scope.discountForm);
```

This results in a GET to /discounts

However this results in a POST to /discounts (expected behaviour)

```
var discountResource = $resource(GLOBALS.apiPath + 'discounts');
var discountResponse = discountResource.save($scope.discountForm);
```

I'm very stuck on this, as I would like to use the first option, with the placeholder declared. But for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

The reason I want option 1 is so that I can decalre it in a factory and inject the resource into my Controllers. Basically i don't want to redeclare it every time I need an API interaction. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 Module.factory("Discount", ["$resource", function ($resource) { return $resource(GLOBALS.apiPath + "discounts/:Id", { Id: "@Id" }, {
            somthingCustomIfNeeded: { method: 'POST', url: GLOBALS.apiPath + "something-custom" }
        }); }]);
```

Notice the `{ Id: "@Id" }` object? It tells Angular how to resolve that :Id variable

Quote from documentation

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the data object (provided when calling an action method). For example, if the defaultParam object is {someParam: '@someProp'} then the value of someParam will be data.someProp

More details here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
(Search for "paramDefaults")

Comment: You Sir, are my hero. This works perfectly, but why? I was under the impression that save() automatically is a POST. In this case we need to define it as such manually?